# Virtualbox/Vagrant shared folder: case sensitivity issue on OS X and Linux

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vagrant

I'm running VirtualBox on a Mac OS X host, with a CentOS guest. I'm using Vagrant to set up a shared folder, so that I can work with code on the host as well as on the guest.

The problem is that the host's filesystem is case-insensitive, but the guest's isn't. So if I run something on the guest like:

```
cd /shared-folder
mkdir foo
mv foo Foo
```

it will fail, since it sees that Foo already exists on the host. That's a simplified example, but I have real cases where I'm trying to use git on the guest, and it ends up doing something similar.

Is there any way to avoid this? I'd prefer to come up with something that will work with all host OSs (Windows, Mac, and Linux).

(One option might be to rsync the host's files to the guest, but I was hoping to avoid that.)

Comment: If you did go the rsync route you could perhaps use the vagrant-sync plugin https://github.com/cromulus/vagrant-rsync

Comment: CentOS file system {ext3,4}should be case sensitive, HFS+ on OS X by default is NOT case sensitive, that is the problem. You may try to use NFS or sshfs instead of default vboxsf.

Comment: It appears to be a Virtualbox shared folder *feature* to support all kinds of underlaying filesystems on the host, including those case insensitive. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/437 Plain stupid, imo. Punched me in the face hard. People with current OSs now make assumptions things are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a bit cheeky of an answer, but you could just use lowercase everywhere. I believe that would solve your problem...

As suggested, rsync is a great option if you want to go another route, and you can include quite extensive include/exclude lists if you are trying to finesse your way around something.